# Custom dropdown default selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using the following styled dropdown menu:

https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

```
<select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Month --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

I am using it to let users select their birth date month. So the first time they signup, they select the month and it's saved. When user wants to edit their profile, I need a way to select the previously selected month for them. Ideas on how to pre-select one of the months are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#mounth option[value='hide']").each(function() {
$(this).remove();
}
```

Note, month is spelled wrong. And you might want to actually store the values as the numeric month, January is 1, etc.